# Multiple mail servers on a Spring application

Tags: java, spring, email

I'm developing an application with Spring. This application has customers, and each customer has his own mail server configuration (port, host, username, password,etc). My application must send emails through the Customers mail servers.
I mean, I cannot use the classic:

`<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">`

There are going to be many MailServerImpls, one per customer, and I will have hundreds of them. Each time a Customer signs in, he is asked for this mail server configuration.

Upon certain actions of the customer, my application must send an email using the Customer mail server.

So, what is the best way to do this with Spring?
I hope the best solution is not to do a `new MailServerImpl()` and set the attributes each time I have to send an email...

Thank you very much.

Comment: May be a nonsense to have a factory of JavaMailSenderImpl? I am thinking on the idea to have a Map of  JavaMailSenderImpl (the customerID would be the Key to the Map). I don't know if having, let's say 200 JavaMailSenderImpl in memory is really problematic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the port, host, username, password,etc from a .properties file or from the database. This way you will have one mailSender implementation but configured different per client.

You could use [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html) and not using a bean but creating an object everytime and sending the mail:

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
email.setSmtpPort(465);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
email.setFrom("user@gmail.com");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
email.addTo("foo@bar.com");
email.send();
```

The values you would store in the database in a relationship to the user.

Comment: But, won't it be a problem to change those parameters every few seconds? I guess concurrency may be a problem if the application has to send two emails at the same time through different mail servers.

Comment: I didn't know about Apache Commons Email. It can be a good option. Mixing your answer with @user3360241 answer I can figure how I will implement it. I'll create a `SimpleEmail` per Customer and I will store it in a Map. I'll use threads in FIFO to send email (using `task:executor`). Each thread will only change the Msg, the To and the Subject.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit vague to me, without going into details how you represent customer and their email server configuration.

What you could do is to have mapping between Customers and their configuration in some dictionary structure.

Accept concurrent requests from customer(with their identifier) and add it to some FIFO queue, then have a thread pool accepting and processing these requests as they come. You would have control on number of worker threads and Email implementation instances which could be reused.

Each thread could be associated with instance of whichever Email implementation you are using  if this implementation has class variables. You could maybe use Email abstraction singleton shared between all threads, where connection properties are only in local scope of method.

Comment: Great idea the FIFO queue for avoiding concurrent changes on the singleton MailServer. I will have to create a FIFO queue per Customer, so I can send 10 emails from different Customers, but if those 10 emails are from the same Customer they will be queued and send one after another. As commented to @Robert-Niestroj I will create an Apache Simple Email per Customer (that will be my Singleton per Customer)

Comment: Technically, you could have only one FIFO for all customers. Allow customer to define multiple Email messages - recipients in a single request, and store such request in FIFO, rather then having one mail per request in FIFO. Apache client allows you to have multiple recipients in a single instance.