# how to configure two different emails in springboot?

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-boot

I know I can use the following properties to automatically create a `JavaMailSender` bean:

```
spring.mail.host=hostname
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=username
spring.mail.password=password
```

However, how can I define these properties to create two `JavaMailSender` beans so I can send emails from different SMTP servers?

I tried defining the following properties:

```
# Properties for sender 1
spring.mail.host=hostname
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=username
spring.mail.password=password

# Properties for sender 2
spring.mail.host1=hostname2
spring.mail.port1=587
spring.mail.username1=username2
spring.mail.password1=password2
```

However, this does not work as I expected, so how can I create two `JavaMailSender` beans using Spring boot?

Comment: Are you paid for this or it's a project for school?

Comment: Just a hint: instead of using email1, email2 use collections: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&ei=tYWjW-b0McnQgAbGgoLgCg&q=using+collections+in+spring+configuration&oq=using+collections+in+spring+configu

Comment: @dbl How would you apply those collections if `spring.mail.*`/`MailProperties` does not support collections? Be aware that these are not just normal properties, these are properties that are used by the `MailAutoConfiguration` and you can't just randomly change them.

Comment: Whoops, never used the built in mailing system so wasn't aware of that. Still there are various techniques to handle this. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220709/multiple-mail-servers-on-a-spring-application

Comment: @dbl True, there are certainly various solutions to this problem, but the initially provided hint wasn't one of them. While the duplicate shows how you can do this with Spring, I'm leaning more towards tailoring this question and the answers specifically to Spring boot rather than the Spring framework in general.

Answer (score 17):

### Creating the beans

Spring boot will only initialize one `JavaMailSender` as soon as it finds the `spring.mail.*` properties. If you need multiple ones, you have to define these beans by yourself. If you only need the properties host, port, username and password, you could use this simple configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class MailConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.mail.primary")
    public JavaMailSender primarySender() {
        return new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.mail.secondary")
    public JavaMailSender secondarySender() {
        return new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    }
}
```

However, this will **not work** if you also want to configure `spring.mail.properties.*` as well. In order to do that, your configuration will be a bit more complex, since you'll have to do the following:

- Create two beans of `MailProperties` using the same `@ConfigurationProperties` as you can see above.
- Use the `MailProperties` in a similar way as Spring boot does within [`MailSenderPropertiesConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/5323095e44d8e2a7d10a9dac61ecb5593c9b4dec/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mail/MailSenderPropertiesConfiguration.java#L46-L74).

---

### Configuration

After that, you can use the `spring.mail.primary.*` properties and `spring.mail.secondary.*` properties as you're used to. For example:

```java
spring.mail.primary.host=host1
spring.mail.primary.port=port1
spring.mail.primary.username=username1
spring.mail.primary.password=password1
spring.mail.secondary.host=host2
spring.mail.secondary.port=port2
spring.mail.secondary.username=username2
spring.mail.secondary.password=password2
```

---

### Usage

After that, you can autowire both `primarySender` and `secondarySender`. Make sure to use the `@Qualifier` annotation to tell Spring which is which:

```java
@Service
public class MailService {
    private JavaMailSender primarySender;
    private JavaMailSender secondarySender;

    public MailService(
        @Qualifier("primarySender") JavaMailSender primarySender,
        @Qualifier("secondarySender") JavaMailSender secondarySender) {
        this.primarySender = primarySender;
        this.secondarySender = secondarySender;
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if we don't know amount of smtp servers ? 2 or 10. And I want to have ability to change configuration without code changes

Comment: Your answer suggest to copy paste those lines.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/5323095e44d8e2a7d10a9dac61ecb5593c9b4dec/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mail/MailSenderPropertiesConfiguration.java#L54-L74
Did I understant you correctly ?

Comment: It does work if you change the name of the property in your application.yml, using javaMailProperties instead of properties, provided that you use JavaMailSenderImpl. Ex : spring.mail.primary.javaMailProperties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable:true

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the mail properties, at least in my case, the mail properties were not read with the @ConfigurationProperties. So I change the solution a bit:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.mail.primarySender")
public JavaMailSender primarySender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    return javaMailSenderWithProperties(javaMailSender);
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.mail.secondarySender")
public JavaMailSender secondarySender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    return javaMailSenderWithProperties(javaMailSender);
}

private JavaMailSender javaMailSenderWithProperties(JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(props);
    return javaMailSender;
}
```

Comment: This is the fix for anyone getting a "Must issue a STARTTLS command first".

Answer (score 0):

## Configure Two different SMTP emails in springboot

## The correct configuration is:

For a correct injection of the javaMailProperties it is necessary to read the keys manually by means of the relative prefix.

### Bean

```
@Configuration
public class EmailConfig {
    public static final String MAIL_SENDER_PRIMARY_KEY = "spring.mail.primary";
    public static final String MAIL_SENDER_PRIMARY_PROPERTIES_KEY = "spring.mail.primary.properties";
    public static final String MAIL_SENDER_SECONDARY_KEY = "spring.mail.secondary";
    public static final String MAIL_SENDER_SECONDARY_PROPERTIES_KEY = "spring.mail.secondary.properties";
    
    public static final String KEY_SEPARATOR = ".";
    public static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = MAIL_SENDER_PRIMARY_KEY)
    public JavaMailSender primarySender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        return javaMailSenderWithProperties(javaMailSender,MAIL_SENDER_PRIMARY_PROPERTIES_KEY);
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = MAIL_SENDER_SECONDARY_KEY)
    public JavaMailSender secondarySender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        return javaMailSenderWithProperties(javaMailSender,MAIL_SENDER_SECONDARY_PROPERTIES_KEY);
    }

    private JavaMailSender javaMailSenderWithProperties(JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender, String prefix) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        if (env instanceof ConfigurableEnvironment) {
            for (PropertySource<?> propertySource : ((ConfigurableEnvironment) env).getPropertySources()) {
                if (propertySource instanceof EnumerablePropertySource) {
                    for (String key : ((EnumerablePropertySource) propertySource).getPropertyNames()) {
                        if (key.startsWith(prefix)) {
                            props.setProperty(key.replaceAll(prefix + KEY_SEPARATOR, EMPTY_STRING), propertySource.getProperty(key).toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(props);
        return javaMailSender;
    }
}
```

### Configuration

#### Properties of PrimarySender

```
spring.mail.primary.username=
spring.mail.primary.password=
spring.mail.primary.host=
spring.mail.primary.port=
spring.mail.primary.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.primary.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.primary.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.primary.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.primary.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
spring.mail.primary.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=
spring.mail.primary.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=
#spring.mail.primary.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.primary.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.primary.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
```

#### Properties of SecondarySender

```
spring.mail.secondary.host=
spring.mail.secondary.port=
spring.mail.secondary.username=
spring.mail.secondary.password=
spring.mail.secondary.protocol=
spring.mail.secondary.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.secondary.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.secondary.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.secondary.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
spring.mail.secondary.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=
spring.mail.secondary.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=
#spring.mail.secondary.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.secondary.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.secondary.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
```

## Usage

```
@Service
public class EmailService {

    private JavaMailSender primarySender;
    private JavaMailSender secondarySender;

    public EmailService (
        @Qualifier("primarySender") JavaMailSender primarySender,
        @Qualifier("secondarySender") JavaMailSender secondarySender) {
        this.primarySender = primarySender;
        this.secondarySender = secondarySender;
    }

    public void sendPrimaryEmail(String from, String to, String subject, String text){
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom(from);
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(text);
        
        primarySender.send(message);

    }

 public void sendSecondaryEmail(String from, String to, String subject, String text) 
       {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom(from);
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(text);
        
        secondarySender.send(message);

    }
}
```