# How To setup multiple mail server with failover in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, email

Sending emails from Spring Boot is as easy as possible.

```
spring:
  mail:
    host: <servername>
```

Plus some additional configuration and off you go.

We rely on an internal email provider that offers two mail servers. Instead of setting these up behind a load balancer, the consumer has to manage the failover itself.
So far, we have therefore only used one of the two servers via the Spring configuration mentioned above.
If this server has a problem, such as the current one where the TLS certificate has expired ‍♂️, the Rediness Check in Spring Actuator floods the log file with error messages.

Does anyone have a solution for using multiple mail servers to provide a fallback scenario?

Comment: check here please : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73816273/2165146

Comment: Thank you, I have also thought about making my own JavaMailSender and looked at the JavaMailSenderImpl. The proposed solution is already close. However, I believe that in order for the actuator to be able to work with it, one should only have one JavaMailSender (Bean), which then internally handles the two alternatives (two or more JavaMailSender). Then you also only have to work with the one (main) JavaMailSender in the EmailService. As soon I have time, I'll try that approach and report back.