# How to configure multiple (unknown amount) different smtp servers in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, smtp

My question looks similar to [how to configure two different emails in springboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424116/how-to-configure-two-different-emails-in-springboot)

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52424779/2674303) is quite cool
But it differs from my needs. I don't know how many smtp servers will be configured. I want to have ability to add email servers only by adding several lines to configuration.

In the code I want to @Autowire them like:

```
@Autowire
private List<JavaMailSenderImpl> javaMailSenders
```

I want to have config like

```
spring.mail.first.host=host1
spring.mail.first.port=port1
spring.mail.first.username=username1
spring.mail.first.password=password1
spring.mail.first.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
...
spring.mail.second.host=host2
spring.mail.second.port=port2
spring.mail.second.username=username2
spring.mail.second.password=password2
spring.mail.second.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
...
spring.mail.fifth.host=host5
spring.mail.fifth.port=port5
spring.mail.fifth.username=username5
spring.mail.fifth.password=password5
spring.mail.fifth.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
```

Could you please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52424779/1915448) with [this answer about creating beans dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75046618/1915448).

For example, let's say you create your own `MailListProperties`:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mail")
public record MailListProperties(Map<String, MailProperties> list) { }
```

Then you can create your own `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` class to create the `JavaMailSenderImpl` beans:

```java
public class DynamicMailsenderBeanDefinitionRegistrar implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {
    private final MailListProperties properties;

    public DynamicMailsenderBeanDefinitionRegistrar(Environment environment) {
        this.properties = Binder
            .get(environment)
            .bind("mail", MailListProperties.class)
            .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        properties.list().forEach((beanName, mailProperties) -> {
            GenericBeanDefinition definition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
            definition.setBeanClass(JavaMailSenderImpl.class);
            definition.setInstanceSupplier(() -> {
                 JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
                 sender.setHost(mailProperties.getHost());
                 // TODO: Here you put the logic to create a JavaMailSenderImpl
                 // You can read the properties defined in MailProperties
                 return sender;
            });
            registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, definition);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

    }
}
```

To register the `DynamicMailsenderBeanDefinitionRegistrar` bean, you can use the following code:

```java
@Bean
public DynamicMailsenderBeanDefinitionRegistrar registrar(Environment environment) {
    return new DynamicMailsenderBeanDefinitionRegistrar(environment);
}
```

To configure the properties, you can use the following properties file:

```
mail.list.first.host=...
mail.list.first.username=...
mail.list.first.password=...
mail.list.second.host=...
mail.list.second.username=...
mail.list.second.password=...
mail.list.third.host=...
mail.list.third.username=...
mail.list.third.password=...
```

In this example, the keys (`first`, `second`, and `third`) in the properties file will become the bean names. You can choose to autowire a specific JavaMailSenderImpl bean like this:

```java
@Autowired
@Qualifier("first")
private JavaMailSenderImpl firstMailSender;
```

Alternatively, you can autowire all the beans of a specific type using a collection:

```java
@Autowired
private List<JavaMailSenderImpl> mailSenders;
```

Comment: Hi, just a code fix:

registry.registerBeanDefinition(**key**, definition);  **key** is undefined

Simply use  registry.registerBeanDefinition(**beanName**, definition);

Finally, you can also use: 
    @Autowired
    private Map<String, JavaMailSenderImpl> beanDefinitionMap;

Answer (score 0):

Why not save the email configuration in the database？

If you must put the configuration in properties you can do like this

```
spring.mail.host=host1,host2
spring.mail.port=port1,port2
spring.mail.username=username1,username2
spring.mail.password=password1,password2
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true,true
```

by this you can you avoid changing Java code when you change the properties, but you need to define a separator to separate different hosts like `,` or something else then prase in code.

I think the second method is hard to maintain Configuration.